# Funny Django Session Behaviour

Tags: python, django, session, django-sessions

In my `settings.py` I have `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True`. I am not sure if that is the right place to do that and if need to import anything first. But it wasn't working on **Chrome** *Version 37.0.2062.124 m* as it persists the session data. My session-dependent page still opens even after closing and re-opening the browser.

So, I manually cleared the session data (`csrftoken`, `sessionid` and `Database Data` in Chrome's Settings session is no longer working at all. Even if I login and try to open `home` page in another tab of the same browser (Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari) I get redirected to `login` page.

```
def index(request): #login page.
    if 'id' in request.session:
        Proceed to Home Page
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Do the needful 
        set request.session['id']
        proceed to Home Page
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html')

def home(request): #homp page
    if 'id' not in request.session:
        redirect to login page
    return render(request, 'myapp/home.html')
```

How do I go about making this work?

Answer (score 0):

I think, `set_expiry(0)` will do the job. here [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.set_expiry)

```
def index(request): #login page.
  if 'id' in request.session:
      Proceed to Home Page
  if request.method == 'POST':
      Do the needful 
      set request.session['id']
      request.session.set_expiry(0)#<---
      proceed to Home Page
  return render(request, 'myapp/index.html')
```